# How to set multiple local variables in one line using T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

```
declare @inserted bit
declare @removed bit
```

I know it's possible to set them like below:

```
SELECT @inserted = 0, @removed = 0
```

but would it be possible to make this even simpler and use something like:

```
SET @inserted, @removed = 0
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

How about:

```
declare @inserted BIT = 0, @removed BIT = 0
```

Works in SQL Server 2008 and up (you didn't specify which **version** of SQL Server....)

**Update:** ok, so you're stuck on SQL Server 2005 - in that case, I believe this is the best you can do:

```
DECLARE @inserted BIT, @removed BIT
SELECT @inserted = 0, @removed = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

> but would it be possible to make this even simpler and use something like:
>
> ```
> SET @inserted, @removed = 0
> ```

I suppose yo mean

```
SET @inserted = @removed = 0
```

No, that is not possible. T-SQL does not support this kind of syntax.